# How we can use group by clause to select single value of highest match

Tags: php, mysql, join

first table : "wp_pc_products"

```
feed_product_name   feed_product_image   price   deeplink    id_merchant
sony xperia c3      abc.png              12000   abc.html     fkt
sony xperia         xyz.png              11000   aaa.html     snd
sony xperia M       pqr.png              10000   bbb.html     fkt
sony xperia z       abc.png              12000   abc.html     fkt
sony xperia z3      xyz.png              11000   aaa.html     snd
sony xperia k       pqr.png              10000   bbb.html     fkt
```

second table: "wp_pc_products_merchants"

```
slug     image
fkt      logo1.png
snd      logo2.png
```

My existing query

```
SELECT p.feed_product_name,
       p.feed_product_image,
       p.price,
       p.deeplink,
       p.id_merchant,
       m.image
FROM wp_pc_products p
JOIN wp_pc_products_merchants m ON m.slug=p.id_merchant
AND (feed_product_name LIKE'%sony%'
     OR feed_product_name LIKE'%xperia%'
     OR feed_product_name LIKE'%c3%')
AND price BETWEEN "11829.3" AND "21968.7"
GROUP BY id_merchant
```

Above query is not working with group by clause.
How can i use group by in above query

Comment: You should pretty much always group by any and all values you want returned excepting things like `max()` or `greatest()`. Also, in order to get the highest single value, you're going to want to wrap the column in `max()`.

Comment: You cannot get the results you want using `GROUP BY`. Look at your query and the data. For `id_merchant = 'fkt'` there are at least two different values for `feed_product_name`. Which one should `MySQL` select in your query for the group having `id_merchant = 'fkt'`? Such a query is not even valid SQL. `MySQL` [accepts it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) until version 5.7.5 and picks one of the values. It cannot guarantee that the query will always return the same value for `p.feed_product_name`.

Comment: i was using this query before=>  SELECT  wp_pc_products.*,wp_pc_products_merchants.image,cashback.percentage FROM wp_pc_products JOIN wp_pc_products_merchants ON wp_pc_products.id_merchant = wp_pc_products_merchants.slug JOIN cashback ON wp_pc_products.shipping = cashback.category_name AND wp_pc_products.id_merchant = cashback.merchant WHERE feed_product_name LIKE '%sony%' and feed_product_name LIKE '%xperia%' and feed_product_name LIKE '%c3%' group by id_merchant

Comment: it was working fine for me. In similar fashion i want one product from one merchant this query was looking for a match in order of position like first word then second so on.  Now we modify it to random match that is the only difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your query to

```
select distinct(m.image),p.feed_product_name,p.feed_product_image,p.price,p.deeplink from wp_pc_products p JOIN wp_pc_products_merchants m ON m.slug=p.id_merchant and (p.feed_product_name like'%sony%' or p.feed_product_name like'%xperia%' or p.feed_product_name like'%c3%' ) and p.price BETWEEN "11829.3" and "21968.7" group by p.id_merchant
```

Or

```
select distinct(m.image),p.feed_product_name,p.feed_product_image,p.price,p.deeplink from wp_pc_products p JOIN wp_pc_products_merchants m ON m.slug=p.id_merchant where (p.feed_product_name like'%sony%' or p.feed_product_name like'%xperia%' or p.feed_product_name like'%c3%' ) and p.price BETWEEN "11829.3" and "21968.7" group by p.id_merchant
```

Comment: forget distinct(m.image) from above query that i edited, then suggest me the best one. I also trying above two queries that you suggest

Comment: I think second one would be best

Comment: Its not my expected result. I have id_merchant column in wp_pc_product table and its repeating the name of merchant and I have slug column in wp_pc_product_merchant table in which merchant name is appearing once this is the only relation i have in both the table. I am expecting one result from each merchant.

Comment: why '-1' Can you please explain?